# How to separate proxy & port from text file & send them to firefox for changing proxy setting

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, proxy, webdriver

I Have a text file named proxy.txt & contains some proxies in format - proxy:port & i am making a program using python 3 where this software check for proxies from file whether proxy is working or not, if site open then it works otherwise carry onto other proxy. I have done everything but got stuck where i need to separate proxy & port from text file & send them to firefox for changing proxy setting & opening site. I don't understand how can i use regex here to separate them from within text file & send them to firefox. Please someone help me. As for now i have only proxy in list & not port so it goes to every proxy with static port which i provided below i.e 8080 it's working fine but when i use list for port also it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` for splitting the url and port. You should also look at documentation at - [using a proxy](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy)

```
for proxy in urls:
          print("Trying proxy %s" % proxy)
          url, port = proxy.split(':')

          try:
               profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
               profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
               profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", url)
               profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(port))
```

Comment: i already tried this but it doesn't set port it only sets ip address

Comment: Can you try casting the port to an integer?   `port = int(port)`

Comment: yeah this is the mistake i was making. It's working now thank you

Comment: sure go ahead .

Comment: whenever i run this program it opens browser using geckodriver as cmd then browser as you can see i force closes the browser using driver.close() command but i don't know how to close that cmd ?

Comment: Sorry I don't get any cmd, May be you need to set the geckodriver.exe path

Comment: like this :- http://imgur.com/a/ICqka
It first open cmd then browser & yeah i have already set the path

Comment: How are you setting the geckodriver path in your script?

Comment: i have added the geckodriver folder path to environment variables

Comment: Not really sure. You can try `driver.quit()` after you close the broswer to see if that closes the cmd window